# make non editable columns editable for newly added row

Tags: javascript, jsp, dojo

I have created enhanced grid in which Column1 is non editable, but user can edit other columns and can update.
But when i add the new row, new row is blank and i should allow to edit and type the data in all columns. But as editable is not true for first column, i could not able to edit column1 of newly added row to give information. 
Please suggest how can i edit column1 for newly added blank row but not for existing row.Please find the fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/Q9GYv/77/

Below is the code:

```
require(['dojo/_base/lang', 'dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid', 'dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore', 'dijit/form/Button', 'dojo/dom', 'dojo/domReady!'],

function (lang, EnhancedGrid, ItemFileWriteStore, Button, dom) {
    /*set up data store*/
    var data = {
          items: [{
            col1 : "John",
            col2 : "aa",
            col3 : "bb",
            col4 : "cC"
         }]
    };

    var store = new ItemFileWriteStore({
        data: data
    });

    /*set up layout*/
    var layout = [
        [{
            'name': 'FirstName',
                'field': 'col1',
                'width': '100px'
        }, {
            'name': 'LastName', editable: 'true',
                'field': 'col2',
                'width': '100px'
        }, {
            'name': 'Designation',editable:'true',
                'field': 'col3',
                'width': '200px'
        }, {
            'name': 'Address',editable:'true',
                'field': 'col4',
                'width': '150px'
        }]
    ];

    /*create a new grid*/
    var grid = new EnhancedGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        store: store,
        structure: layout,
        rowSelector: '20px',
        canEdit: function(inCell, inRowIndex) {
            if(inRowIndex === 0) {
                return true;
            }
            return this._canEdit;
        }
    });

    /*append the new grid to the div*/
    grid.placeAt("gridDiv");

    /*Call startup() to render the grid*/
    grid.startup();


    var button = new Button({
        onClick: function () {
            console.log(arguments);
            store.newItem({
                col1: "",editable:true,
                col2: "",
                col3: "",
                col4: "New Row"
            });

        }
    }, "addRow");
});
```

--EDIT--

Please suggest how can i make Column1 as **editable** **when adding a new row** and **read-only when editing the existing row in the grid**. Please find the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Q9GYv/77/.

Answer (score 1):

When creating your grid, you can override the canEdit function so that you can specify which rows cannot be modified. See below:

```
canEdit: function(inCell, inRowIndex) {
   if(inRowIndex === 0) { //Note that you can apply any conditions you want to this
      return false;
   }
   return this._canEdit;
}
```

You would also need to make your rows editable by default and I would suggest not allowing the 'id' row to be mutable as you're running a ItemFileWriteStore and that doesn't allow for changing an item's ID after it's been inserted.

I've updated your JSFiddle with these updates: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9GYv/75/

New fiddle with column 1 being uneditable for existing rows: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9GYv/78/

Comment: Thanks @Richard. My requirement is different. I have a grid which allows user to add a blank row and should able to edit all columns to insert the data and edit the exisitng row in the grid and update the data. When new row is added all rows should be editable, similarly when user edits the existing row he should not able to edit the column1 , it should be readonly column as in http://jsfiddle.net/Q9GYv/76/. Please suggest how can i make Column1 as editable when adding a new row and read-only when editing the existing row in the grid.

Comment: Then I need to ask why you're trying to change an identifier? Perhaps you don't want the first column to be an identifier? Or what use case do you have that you would even want to change the identifier of an item after the first write.

Comment: Please see the original question , i modified the details. Requirement is first column is not an identifier , it shows firstName of the person and that field is non editable once inserted. But when user want to create new row he should be able to give all details in the row. As you mentioned first column is not an identifier. Please find the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Q9GYv/77/ .  @Richard.

Comment: One more quick question then: How do you define an existing vs a new row? Does a new row become an existing one once it goes out of focus?

Comment: Please see the below code in http://jsfiddle.net/Q9GYv/77/ .                 var button = new Button({ onClick: function () .. when user click on Add Blank Row button, i am creating a new row inside the store using store.newItem({.. .  to create a new blank row and in that i tried to make column1 as editable using editable:true but it is not working. Thanks @Richard.

Comment: No I think you're misunderstanding. I understand that when you click Add Blank Row, it's considered a new row. But at what point is your row considered an existing row? When does it change from being a new row to an existing row. You'll need to define that in order to determine what the code will look inside the canEdit function

Comment: Ok..Existing row is the data loaded when the grid loads..and when we click on Add Blank Row and give the information in all the columns and once user click on Insert Row button, data is inserted in the database and again the grid with all the data is loaded from database which contains the newly added row information too. And Richard iam new to dojo ,trying my best to understand :). @Richard

Comment: No problem. I would highly recommend you go through and read up on some of the API docs on the widgets you're trying to use though. They can be found here: https://dojotoolkit.org/api/

If you understand the tools you're using and their functionality it actually makes this quite a simple problem. When loading your initial data, you just need to figure out how many existing rows you have and store it into some variable. Afterwards, your canEdit function has all the options you need to determine what column and row someone is trying to edit. I've update the post above with a newer fiddle.